# antd divider component is giving errors

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to use `antd-divider` in my react component like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Divider } from 'antd'


class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Count>
          <span>Total 1 : 0</span>
          <Divider type='vertical' />
          <span>Total 2: 0</span>
        </Count>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Example
```

but iam getting an error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'antd/lib/divider'

i even searched in the issues of `antd` but couldn't find anything related.

Note: All other components like `Button` are working

Comment: try `import Divider from 'antd/lib/divider';`

Comment: did you install it by `yarn add antd` ?

Comment: all other components like `Button ` are working

Answer (score 0):

This one `import Divider from 'antd/lib/divider';`

Or this one `import { Divider } from 'antd';`
should work

If they don't work, try to shutdown your server and start it again `yarn start`